# How to change the amount of increments in pyplot axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi probably quite a simple question but.. 
When plotting a graph using matplotlib.pyplot my Y axis goes from -0.04 to 0.03 which is fine but there are 8 labels for increments (eg 0.03,0.02,0.01 etc.). I need more maybe 16 or so.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_yticks()` to change the tick locations. For example:

```
import scipy, pylab
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(scipy.randn(8))
ax.set_yticks(scipy.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.25))
fig.show()
```

`pylab.yticks()` is another option.
[image: More ticks]
<sub>(source: [stevetjoa.com](http://up.stevetjoa.com/moreticks.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Matplotlib has several different algorithms for choosing tick locations automatically, and e.g. LinearLocator or MaxNLocator may suit your purpose. See [the major_minor demo](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html#pylab-examples-major-minor-demo1) for how to use Locators in general, and [the ticker api documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html) for the various Locators available. The documentation for the individual classes is somewhat sparse, but guessing based on the argument names tends to work fine.