# How to modify the step of y axis in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code:

```
ax.set_ylim(0.000001,0.01) 
ax.set_yscale('log')
```

How can I do to have the `y` vary between 0.000001 and 0.01 with a step of 0.01. That is to say, in order to have `y` increments like 10^-6, 10^-5 and so on, I'd like to have 10^-6, 10^-4 until 10^-2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013350/how-to-change-the-amount-of-increments-in-pyplot-axis

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want ?

```
import numpy as np
ax.set_yticks(np.logspace(-6,-2,num=5))
```

`np.logspace(-6,-2,num=5)` gives :

```
array([  1.00000000e-06,   1.00000000e-05,   1.00000000e-04,
         1.00000000e-03,   1.00000000e-02])
```

Comment: It is far better to change the `Locator` and `Formatter` than to use `set_yticks` directly.

Comment: @tcaswell might helps more to give some code snippets for this case ;)

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html  `ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(mticker.LogForamatter(base=100.0))` more-or-less works, but looks a bit funnier than I expect it to.