# PyPlot- Manipulating the y axis without explicitly setting the range (setting the number of ticks and "round" numbers)

Tags: python, matplotlib

In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013350/how-to-change-the-amount-of-increments-in-pyplot-axis), the answer to a similar question suggested using something like:

```
ax.set_yticks(scipy.arange(-1.5,1.5,0.25))
```

for setting the y axis ticks.

In my code, I have a list X (of an arbitrary range) I want to plot. I want to set the y axis so that it would show exactly, say, 5 ticks. My current code looks something like-

```
ax.set_yticks(scipy.arange(min(X),max(X),(max(X)-min(X))/5))
```

Which seems quite messy. Is there a cleaner way of setting the number of ticks on the y axis without using the min/max functions?

---

Moreover, I'd like to show only "round" numbers (say, numbers with the least number of significant digits possible to plot 5 values such that all values are between them) on the axis if possible (even if it means that the plot won't use the entire range).

e.g. if

```
X=[0.166, 0.164, 0.172, 0.169, 0.188, 0.184, 0.191, 0.183, 0.192]
```

Then I'd like the axis ticks to be

```
{0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2}
```

,rather then the ugly numbers I get using (max(X)-min(X))/5) increments

> What is the cleanest way of acheiving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `MaxNLocator` ([Documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MaxNLocator))

Example:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=5-1))
```

This should give you 5 ticks at *nice* locations.